# "module has no exports" error - works fine on stackblitz but fails locally

Tags: node.js, next.js, mjs

I'm trying to get up and running with [shikiji](https://github.com/antfu/shikiji) (a rewrite of [shiki](https://github.com/shikijs/shiki)). As such, I've created [this minimal example Next.js 13 project](https://github.com/ben519/shikiji-test). It's the boilerplate project you get with `npx create-next-app@latest myproject` except I've installed shikiji and added a simple import statement here

```
// sr/app/page.js

import { getHighlighter } from "shikiji"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>Hello World</div>
  )
}
```

Now when I `npm run dev` I get the following error

> error ./node_modules/shikiji/dist/index.mjs
> export 'getHighlighterCore' (reexported as 'getHighlighterCore') was not found in './core.mjs' (module has no exports)

[image]

The weird thing is, the author of shikiji tried to [reproduce the error on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/ben519/shikiji-test) but could not. There is nothing particularly special or unusual about my setup.

Here's my `package.json` for reference

```
{
  "name": "shikiji-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "shikiji": "^0.6.3",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

**Note:** The error does not occur if I run `npx create-next-app@latest` and use Typescript.

What's going on here?

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: @RichardDunn I'm using v19.4.0 locally. It looks like StackBlitz is using v16.20.0.

Comment: @Ben Are you able to use `client component`? I see the error disappears in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I need it to work in a server component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shikiji is an ESM-focused rewrite of shiki. In order to run esm focused package. Add below webpack configuration in next.config.js file. It worked in my case using the same configuration.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (
    config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
  ) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      type: "javascript/auto",
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It appears to work, but I need to test it a little more. I'll award the bounty sometime today or tomorrow. Cheers

Comment: Worked for the error `export 'addClassToHast' (reexported as 'addClassToHast') was not found in './core.mjs' (module has no exports)` as well, thanks!